# SQL php connect three tables

Tags: php, sql

I am  a begginer programmer and I want to ask something about SQL and PHP. So, I have 3 tables in the database, the first one is a table 't1'that store information about a user

```
(id--> primary key,username, password , email),
```

the second one is about skills 't2'

```
( id--> primary key, skills,level)
```

and the third one is about more speciffic details for the user

```
(id--> primary key, years, language).
```

That I want is the table t2 and t3 stored in a specific user that already exists in t1. How can I achieve that?

I tried to connect the three tables like this by addind each one id to the the other table for instance the t2 table contains the id of the t1 as a column and the t3 table contains the id of the t1 and the id of the t2.

My question is how when I insert data in t3 can take the t1.id and t2.id in order to show all information of three tables in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t3` (
  `degree` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `exp_years` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,

  `department` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `t3_id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `t2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t3_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`t3_id`),
  KEY `t1id` (`t1_id`),
  KEY `t2_d` (`t2_id`),
  KEY `t2_id` (`t2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `fullname` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `webpage` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,

  `rating` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `t2_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t2_id`),
  KEY `t1_id` (`t1_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=147 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `t1_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `cpassword` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, particularly this bit: `That I want is the table t2 and t3 stored in a specific user that already exists in t1. How can I achieve that?`. Please post some example SQL of both your table structure and what you've tried

Comment: Some piece of advise: Rename your tables. This is not understandable. Just call them something like 'users, skills, language' or something. If you return to these tablesnames later, you don't know what they mean. Tablesnames should explain themselves in a way another person could tell what it is for

Comment: @Bojangles .. I post the tables in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column `userId` in your tables t2 and t3 and specify the ID of the user stored in t1 when you add something in t2 or t3.

After that, you can fetch all information about a user by using SQL joins : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need one more table to link the users to the skills, years and language:

t4 -> t4primarykey,t1foreignkey,t2foreignkey,t3foreignkey

or possibly better:

t4 -> t4primarykey,t1foreignkey,t2foreignkey
t5 -> t5primarykey,t1foreignkey,t3foreignkey

It is important from the start off to design your tables so they can be linked this way.  Antoine's answer will also work but will lead to data duplication in larger data structures.
In an ideal world, none of your tables would contain data held in other tables.  Look up 'normal forms' in database design and your sql life will eventually become much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have no relationships between your tables, so currently you have no way to select anything from t2 or t3 based on a particular user.
You could just add "username" to your tables t2 and t3, and then each table data is based on each username.
So for example you can then select their "skills level" from t2 table and "language" from t3 table based on their username (as username will be in each table)

This is a basic suggestion though, you should read up on table relationships and foreign keys.